# MultipartFile is null when sending a file with Rest template

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, multipartform-data, resttemplate

Hi i have 2 separate apps.

the first one is sending post request:
i am trying to send a file to the second app

```
public static String httpPostMultipartFile(String url, File file) throws IOException{
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.add("file", file); // load file into parameter
    HttpHeaders headers1 = new HttpHeaders();
    headers1.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    String result = restTemplate.exchange(
            url,
            HttpMethod.POST,
            new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(parameters, headers1),
            String.class
        ).getBody();
    return result;
```

this is the second app  which is getting post request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fileupload/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/plain")
@ResponseBody
public String save(@RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file, @RequestParam(required = false) Boolean suggestTranspose, @RequestParam(value = "transformers", required = false) String transformersString, @RequestParam(required = false) Integer brandId) throws Exception {
.....
}
```

But in my second app the MultipartFile  is acctually null from the rest call

i have found this link which havnt helped me
[link 1](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjJ94WR3frOAhUFDxoKHVT_CcQQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F11358069%2Fspring-rest-multipartfile-file-is-always-null&usg=AFQjCNES7ttKiQrUz060JZI-k-yih23gEQ)

[link 2](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjJ94WR3frOAhUFDxoKHVT_CcQQFgghMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F20678586%2Fspring-rest-multipartfile-file-is-always-null-when-do-upload-file&usg=AFQjCNFv0yE6ET38BemUsSF5uUGv1AYYbw)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your httpPostMultipartFile method should be like below. You need to add the file using `new FileSystemResource(file.getPath())`.

```
public static String httpPostMultipartFile(String url, File file) throws IOException{
   RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> multipartMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();     
        multipartMap.add("file", new FileSystemResource(file.getPath()));
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity<Object>(multipartMap, headers);         
        String result = restTemplate.exchange(
                url,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                request,
                String.class
            ).getBody();

        return result;
}
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained what you changed and why.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example (tested by me) of how to call a web service that contains file as @RequestParam using RestTemplate:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        FileSystemResource value = new FileSystemResource(new File("src/myFile.txt"));
        map.add("file", value);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost/api/ws/myws", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
    }
}
```